# Azure SqlDatabase can't access after copy

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I copied many times an sqlDatabase but i can only access with my user.

As read in the documentation, the principal became the user who started the operation.

So i tried using the sql statement to copy the database logged as the sql server administrator, but invain.

I can't access to copied database with the original sql server principal.

I need to keep this super user on all the server databases.

Comment: did you copied database to same logical server  .. or a different one

Comment: on the same server

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem. I can connect to all the databases copied.

There is only a visible difference in Sql Server Management Studio.

It is a connection option:

- if I connect with Connect to Database: *default*, I can see all the databases on my server.
- if i choose a single one, i can see only it.

Comment: You saw this difference because logging into master (what happens when you're logging into default) is not the same as logging into the specific database you want. You don't have the scope to see the other databases when you log into a specific database.